# Did Firebase authentication change over night?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase

I am using Firebase email authentication. It worked pretty well yesterday, but for some reason, it suddenly stopped working this morning, and I have not touched the authentication part in the code at all. I am wondering if there is any changes in Firebase that i am not aware? or I did something may affect it?

Here is the code in controller:

```
// Home controller
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseAuth) {

    // Auth Logic will be here
    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://xxxx/");

    var loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);

    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.SignIn = function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();            //To prevent from refresh
         var email = $scope.user.username + '@whateverdomain.com';
         var password = $scope.user.password;
         console.log('Authentication start inside SignIn:' + );
         loginObj.$authWithPassword({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                })
                .then(function(user) {
                    //Success callback
                    console.log('Authentication successful');
                    $location.path('/dashboard');
                }, function(error) {
                    //Failure callback
                    console.log(error.code);
                    if(error.code === "INVALID_USER") {
                        console.log('INVALID_USER');
                        $scope.loginForm.username.$invalid = true;
                    }
                    if(error.code === "INVALID_PASSWORD") {
                        console.log('INVALID_Password');
                        $scope.loginForm.password.$invalid = true;
                    }

                });
    }
}]);
```

Here is the view:

```
<body ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<div class="container-login">
    <div style="padding-bottom:0px; ">
        <h1> Login</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="form-signin" name="loginForm" style="color:#C3BCB6;">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':loginForm.username.$invalid}">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Input your username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="12"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : loginForm.password.$invalid }">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-minlength="8"></input>
        </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="SignIn($event)" ng-disabled="!user.username || !user.password" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

When authentication success, the user is supposed to redirect to the dashboard, or when it failed, it will show error message in the console.
Currently, it only shows "Authentication starts", but no "Authentication success" or any error message, from error.code.

I even checked out previous git commit, the authentication still did not work. Any thoughts? thanks!

Comment: this is strange.... the authentication works on my another computer.....exactly same code i pull from my own repo on github....

Comment: The code looks correct. Perhaps some files are cached incorrectly on your first computer, or there's an issue with its connection.

Comment: You have an extra `});` in your first .then() call. That would be a syntax error. Are you on the latest versions? Always a good place to start.

Comment: the extra }); is a typo, thank you for spotting it, but this is not the issue. I still could not login in on one of my computer, but can do it in other two computers, by pulling the exactly same code from github.